# Creating a floating box which stays within a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a div 'floater' which acts similar to a fixed div (stuck in a specific position regardless of scrolling), but when it hits the boundaries of the div it is within, it stops being fixed.

When the scrollbar is at the top, it should have the div placed at 0 within the containing div (positioned say 100 pixels from the top) and when the scrollbar reaches the bottom, it should prevent the floater from going outside the container. The height of the floater would be static, but the container height would be dynamic.

I've seen this type of this all over the place, but can't figure out how to find a good example for it.

I'd like to avoid jQuery if possible, as I imagine it should only require some simple JavaScript to determine the current position relative to the div it is within.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay folks, here is a complete solution. I've only tested this in Firefox and IE, but it should work across the board (I think). This is straight JavaScript and jQuery is **not** used. The first JS function makes sure the height returned works in various browsers.

**Edit** - I improved on this, see below.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
* {margin:0;padding:0;}
#header {height:300px;width:100%;background:#888;}
#main {height:800px;width:70%;background:#eee;float:left;}
#side {width:30%;height:auto;background:#ddd;float:left;position:relative;}
#floater {height:400px;width:90%;background:#dcd;top:0px;position:absolute;}
#footer {height:300px;width:100%;background:#888;clear:both;}
</style>
<script>
function getPageY() {
 var height = 0;
 if(typeof(window.pageYOffset) == 'number') {
  height = window.pageYOffset;
 }
 else if(document.body && document.body.scrollTop) {
  height = document.body.scrollTop;
 }
 else if(document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) {
  height = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
 }
 return height;
}
onload=function() {
 window.onscroll = scroll;
 function scroll() {
  ybox.value = "this: "+getPageY();
  var f = document.getElementById("floater");
  var y = getPageY()-300; // minus header height
  var divh = document.getElementById("main").offsetHeight;
  if (divh > 400) { // greater than floater height
   divh -= 400; // minus floater height
   if (y < 0) y = 0;
   else if (y > divh) y = divh;
   f.style.top = y+"px";
  }
 }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="main"></div>
<div id="side"><div id="floater">Float Content<br />
<input name="ybox" id="ybox"></div></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This works, but with images it is extremely jumpy. I modified it to use a fixed position when it should be stuck in a position. Replace the three matching lines with this for a smoother result:

```
if (y < 0) {y = 0;f.style.position = "absolute";}
else if (y > divh) {y = divh;f.style.position = "absolute";f.style.top = divh+"px";}
else {f.style.position = "fixed";f.style.top = 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented this and its pretty good. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/creating-a-floating-html-menu-using-jquery-and-css/. But this is done using jquery only. Ill let you know if icome across any links with just plain javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, but it doesn't deal with containing the floater in div. Using that example, the floater should remain within the side column area and never go past the footer.